# Can the OpenAdaptxt library be used for iOS?

Tags: ios, static-libraries

I'm currently developing a keyboard for iOS and it is currently lacking an autocorrect predictive keyboard engine. I found the following library online http://openadaptxt.sourceforge.net (by Keypoint who also license their software for the same means). Would it be possible to use it on iOS or would I be wasting my time? Is there another library I should be using?
Have their been other similar projects made for iOS?

Edit: I found the following open sourced project which seems to have used it successfully but doesn't provide any instructions as to how to do so. Check it out here: https://github.com/k3a/OctopusKeyboard

Thanks!

Comment: did you success to build OpenAdaptxt library for ioS ?

Comment: @gstream79 nope, made my own corpus, n-gram, etc